# VLC - gapless cue support

Tags: audio, vlc

Most of my music is ripped `flac`'s with `cue`'s. I listen to albums with `cue` mainly because of *last.fm* scrobbling, but I want the same experience of gapless playback as listening to whole `flac` using VLC (I very like it's simplicity). Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `Music on Console` provides gapless playback.

Comment: There are plans to [add gapless playback in VLC Player 4.0](https://www.neowin.net/news/vlc-40-to-drop-support-for-older-platforms-while-adding-new-ui-and-gapless-playback).